# Ward Boundary of major city of india

Tags: data, india

i am looking for ward Boundary of major city of India Like Jhansi, i have try some sites where ward boundary is available like urban master plan and sildeshere but not found

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, have you tried looking on the specific city GIS website for this data download?

Comment: yes i have try  Municipal corporations  side  but they don't have  so i request if any one have ward boundary

Comment: In South Africa, ward boundaries fall under the Demarcation Board, so the shapefiles are available on their website. Does India not have a similar body in charge of the ward boundaries?

Comment: If this is likely to be open data then asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown) where you can select **India** as *Country* and **Administrative areas** as *Subject*. You should receive three polygon shapefiles.

Load the "IND_adm3.shp" shapefile into your GIS software, open the *Attribute Table* and in the `NAME_3` field, search for 'Jhansi'.

In QGIS, you can write an expression like:

```
"NAME_3" LIKE 'Jhansi'
```

There should only be one feature:

[image: Jhansi]

---

Jhansi also exists in the `NAME_2` field where four features exist but I believe those show the Jhansi district and not the city.